# How to cancel Observable.timer with rxjava2?

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have a retry mechanism in my code, I'm using below lines to execute my retry logic. For example, I generate an random milliseconds to delay my execution. I would like to cancel this timer when timer ticks to 30 * 1000 milliseconds. How can I cancel this timer and execute my logic immediately.

```
//register retryWhen
Observable.retryWhen(new RetryWhenException());

//retry code.
public class RetryWhenException implements Function<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>>{       
public Observable<?> apply(final Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) throws Exception {
            return observable.zipWith(Observable.range(1, count + 1), new BiFunction<Throwable, Integer, Wrapper>() {
                @Override
                public Wrapper apply(Throwable throwable, Integer integer) throws Exception {
                    return new Wrapper(throwable, integer);
                }
            }).flatMap(new Function<Wrapper, Observable<?>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<?> apply(Wrapper wrapper) throws Exception {
                    long delay = 60 * 1000;
                    //How can I add some code here to cancel this time and execute this api call immediately if I receive a event like network gets back?
                    return Observable.timer(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understands correctly your question, you want to able to combine multiple conditions to the retry, meaning retry will happen after certain amount of time at most (the timer), or even earlier after some event will happen (network is connected).
In this case, you need to combine this 2 events, first, you will need some `Observable` that notifies regarding network events (it's a different discussion how to create it, shouldn't be a problem to wrap system broadcast events with Observable), then you can do something like this:

```
private Observable<NetworkState> networkStateObservable;

public class RetryWhenException implements Function<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {
    public Observable<?> apply(
            final Observable<? extends Throwable> observable) throws Exception {
        return observable.zipWith(Observable.range(1, count + 1), Wrapper::new)
                .flatMap(wrapper -> {
                    long delay = 60 * 1000;
                    Observable<NetworkState> networkConnectedEvents =
                            networkStateObservable.filter(networkState -> networkState.isConnected())
                               take(1);
                    Observable<Long> timer = Observable.timer(delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                    return Observable.amb(Arrays.asList(networkConnectedEvents, timer));
                });
    }
}
```

network state `Observable` is filtered to get only notifications when connected, also the `take(1)` is to ensure that after first time we'll get notification will unsubscribe from it (no further need to listen).
`amb()` operator seems like the exact fit here as it will choose the `Observable` that will emit firs, and will unsubscribe the other, meaning in case that network `Observable` emits before the timer, the timer `Observable` will be unsubscribed (= timer will be cancelled).

EDIT:

removed wrong takeUntil(networkConnectedEvents), it's not needed as amb will do unsubscription if needed.

Comment: Hi yosriz,

Could you please help take a look how should I emit networkStateObservable correctly? I posted my code below. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for reply. This is exactly what I was looking for. I created a network Observable wrapper as what you described, 
it seems networkStateObservable didn't emit after onNetworkChanged() was called(state.isConnected() is true). 
How can I make networkStateObservable emit correctly? Thanks so much.
I called below lines in

```
e.onNext(state);  
 e.onComplete();
```

was I wrong to emit networkStateObservable?

```
Observable<NetworkState> networkStateObservable = getNetworkObservableWrapper();
public Observable<NetworkState> getNetworkObservableWrapper() {
        return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<NetworkState>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<NetworkState> e) throws Exception {
                final NetworkChangedListener listener = new NetworkChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNetworkChanged(NetworkState state) {
                        //Below lines were called, but Observable.amb(Arrays.asList(networkConnectedEvents, timer)); didn't work.                       
                        e.onNext(state);
                        e.onComplete();
                    }
                };
                registerNetworkChanged(listener);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It seems it was caused by .takeUntil(networkConnectedEvents). if I removed this line, it worked fine.

Comment: yeah, actually I put it by mistake, I removed it from answer, amb will do the cancellation (unsubscription from timer if needed)

Comment: guessing the problem: if your `registerNetworkChanged()` overwrite the existing network changed listener, what might happened is that this Observable subscribed twice (one at the amb and when at the takeUntil) thus the second takeUntil might overwrite the existing listener.

Comment: few comments, following my guess for the root cause, a) when you register to network change events, add a listener instead of setting b) besides that you should add unregistering from the listener logic using `ObservableEmitter.setCancelable()`

Comment: Thanks  very much for explain.